# exchange 2010 storage on hyper-v

Tags: exchange, hyper-v, storage

Working on planning new Exchange 2010 to migrate my existing email infrastructure on it.

- I have ~120 users with ~3-8 Gb mailboxes and a lot of public folders (~80 Gb). Total used mailbox space on current server is ~700 Gb
- I have 12 3.5" drive bays, Xeon E5-1650 v3, 64 GB of RAM and high-end LSI 9271-8i raid card with BBU connected to 8 drive bays with 8 1Tb WD Raid edition drives (7200k) in these bays.
- I have 4 empty bays connected to onboard LSI 3008 RAID controller (and some HDDs).
- I have 3 another low-loaded VMs on this host.

RAID 10 pool on whole disks is fastest, but Microsoft recommends to provide dedicated storage for mailbox databases and don't mix Exchange DBs and logs, OS volume and another virtual machines on the same physical disks. I'm planning to use Veeam B&R free as a backup solution. And I want to depoly second server as a DAG member on another hypervisor.

How can I use my storage in most effective way? All 8 discs as one RAID10 volume? Dedicated RAID volume for hypervisor OS with exchange system VHD on it and another raid volume for exchange data? Dedicated volumes for all exchange databases ang logs? Pass-through storage or VHDs?

I want to keep things simple but don't miss something important in perfomance and scalibility.

P.S. Exchange 2010 Server Role Requirements Calculator suggests me to use 7 LUNs in my setup. I think what it is too complicated

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple with all 8 disks in one RAID 10 volume. That will aggregate the IOPS of the disks. Splitting Exchange between volumes allows you to optimize RAID for the files, e.g. RAID5 for DB files and RAID10 for log files, but this would complicate extended ownership of the host and decrease flexibility in the long run.

Use fixed size VHDX files, and store all data in data disks attached to the SCSI controller. If you want multiple volumes then do 1 volume per VHDX.